# Creating a Search Box/Data - Joomla v1.5.25

Tags: joomla

I need help on Joomla v1.5.25, I already have it running and everything seems fine.
I wish to add a list of data for example a list of KFC Outlets, and enable a search box so that visitors can just key in the City Name of the KFC outlet that they are looking for and the result will be a list of KFC Outlets matching the City Name keyed in.

Apologize if this question have been asked previously, and I am new to this. Hope someone can shed some light or point me to the proper site for this  question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you can use some1else's work - I suggest

Check out http://www.kfc.com/storelocator/Default.aspx?address=new%20york 
And take the results on that page
This is only good for USA - if you need all countries then you will need to go through all their sites and collect results for all the pages.

or you should:

- create a new table in mysql each row should have info about a kfc outlet (address, phone, open hours, etc...)
- create a new joomla component or module in which you should have your sql select query to search and then return the list of results.
- You can then create a form on any page for searching

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. I hate to ask but i am actually no techie or programmer. Anyway i can achieve this by having a guide for a noob?

Comment: This is not what i would call a noob task. You can learn how but you will need to learn some sql, php, javascript and html. I would start by creating a mysql table to store your data (download mysql workbench - much better than phpmyadmin). then create a joomla module to display the data (download a simple module then modify it). Google has all the answers you will need (just make sure to ask the right thing)